# Is subtracting covariances legal in the case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance

I want to find the Covariance of $cW$ and $Y - cV$. Which of the following is correct?

$$\mathrm{Cov}(cW, y - cV) = c \mathrm{Cov}(W, Y) + c^2 \mathrm{Cov}(W, V)$$

$$\mathrm{or}$$

$$\mathrm{Cov}(cW, y - cV) = c \mathrm{Cov}(W, Y) - c^2 \mathrm{Cov}(W, V)$$

Answer (score 0):

(I'm going to assume that $V$, $W$, and $Y$ are all random variables, and that where you wrote $Z$ you meant $Y$.)

We know that $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$, so in your case,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{cov}(cW,Y-cV) &= E[(cW)(Y-cV)] - E[cW]E[Y-cV] \\
&= E[cWY - c^{2}WV] - E[cW]E[Y-cV] \\
&= cE[WY] - c^{2}E[WV] - cE[W]E[Y] + c^{2}E[W]E[V] \\
&= c\Big\{E[WY] - E[W]E[Y]\Big\} - c^{2} \Big\{ E[WV] - E[W]E[V] \Big\} \\
&= c \cdot \mathrm{cov}(W,Y) - c^{2} \cdot \mathrm{cov}(W,V).
\end{aligned}
$$